# How to create SOQL query problem

Tags: soql

I have two objects names job and job allocation both are custom objects...

Fields in job_c object:

1. jobid(auto number)
2. Job name
3. Title

Fields in Joballocation_c

1. joballocation_id(autonumer)
2. Joballocatio Name
3. Title
4. Job(Lookup relationship to job)

Requirement is I want a new job allocation id with latest job...

```
List<job_c> latest = [select Id from job_c CreatedDate order by desc Limit1];
For(job_c nj:latest)
{Setjob.add(Nj.id);
}

List<joballocation_c> latest = [select Id from joballocation_c where Id IN:Setjob CreatedDate order by desc Limit 1];
```

It is not correct working properly

I want a new querry...joballocation is child object of job...I want a new job allocation with latest job...

Comment: "order by" should be before field name, so your first soql should be [select Id from job_c order by CreatedDate desc Limit1]

Answer (score 1):

Try this SOQL

```
List<Job__C> listJob=[Select id,(Select id from jobAllocationRelationshipName__r order by createdDate desc limit 1) from job_c order by createdDate desc limit 1];
```

This single SOQL will do your task. "jobAllocationRelationshipName__R " is the relationship name. Check your schema for exact name .

Checkout the SOQL tutorial [here](http://blog.jeffdouglas.com/2010/02/22/soql-how-i-query-with-thee-let-me-count-the-ways/).

Comment: in the job object there is no relation with job allocation so i got this error did not understand the jobAppliction_r...

Comment: Yes this way you can query the child along with parent. This should solve the problem.

Comment: In jobApplication there will be a relation for Job in lookup field. check that out.

Comment: In the job_c object have jobid name newjobId_c,title name title_c,

Comment: go to jobApplication , there will be a lookup of job__C, open the lookup, you will see child relationship name. Thats the name you should use in SOQL

Comment: In the job_c object have jobid name newjobId_c,title name title_c,and allocation have Id and relationship with job field name is job_c then how can write query..plz give example....plz

Comment: in the Settings> select objects> jobApplications.
in that you will see Job(lookup). Click it. there will be child relationship name. use it in query

Answer (score 0):

Error: Compile Error: Didn't understand relationship 'Job_Application__r' in FROM part of query call. If you are attempting to use a custom relationship, be sure to append the '__r' after the custom relationship name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names. at line 47 column 25 error....
 susanoo chidori